# Asynchronously executed command captures REPL input

Tags: julia, stdin, sudo

I'm running an external command like this in Julia REPL:

```
stream, process = open(`sudo cat file.txt`, "w", STDOUT)
```

The command, `sudo cat file.txt`, when executed standardly in shell, asks for a password and then prints the file.

So I paste this into the REPL, press enter and it immediately returns, because the process runs asynchronously. Everything works as expected so far.

But when I start typing something else into the REPL, the characters I'm typing don't appear on screen (`sudo` is asking for the password), because the asynchronous process is (presumably) "stealing" the text I'm typing.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: I expanded the answer, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: is it not just expecting you to type a password?

Comment: As Tasos mentioned, it's probably just asking for a password. Do you not see the `[sudo] password for xxx:` prompt?

Comment: @FengyangWang @TasosPapastylianou of course it is, but it should be reading the password from `stream`, not stealing it from the REPL. At least according to documentation of `open`.

Comment: The documentation is correct that the STDIN is `stream`, but `sudo` does not read from STDIN. See https://serverfault.com/questions/731886/why-does-password-entering-work-in-a-piped-sudo-command/731943 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of how `open` works is correct. As you've clarified in the comments, your question is about why `sudo` is asking for the password in the terminal instead of reading from `stream`. This is explained well by [Bob](https://serverfault.com/users/174582/bob) at https://serverfault.com/a/731943. Quoting the relevant parts of the answer:

> Actually, a typical invocation of sudo does not read the password from stdin at all. Instead, sudo will directly access the controlling terminal (a tty or pty, via the /dev/tty special file) and output the prompt and read characters directly. This can be seen in the tgetpass.c file in the sudo source.

`sudo` is capable of reading from stdin using the `-S` flag. You can use this if you'd like to write the password yourself from the script:

> Otherwise, if you specifically request sudo to read from stdin, e.g. with the -S flag -- and it will also write the prompt to stderr. This is the case where MadHatter's answer applies.